# ASP.NET MVC Routing: Works in Dev Env but not always in Prod Env

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, asp.net-mvc-routing

My dev env folder structure is different than my prod env.  The beginning of urls in my prod env look like: /dirs/xxx/ctrlr/action/id    My dev env urls do not have the /dirs/xxx nodes; they simply look like: /ctrlr/action/id

When I publish my project and run in the prod env, sometimes my code maps the additional prod url nodes properly, sometimes it does not and I get a 404.

I am examining the parts of my project for which url mapping is occurring properly and comparing to those parts for which it is not, but so far I am missing the solution.  If you can help it would be greatly appreciated.  My apologies if I have missed a StackOverflow blog that already answers this question; I have Googled it to death.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your dev environment up to match your production environment?

Right click your MVC project, then edit properties then select web.

[image]

In this screenshot I'm using IIS Express - change your URL directory to /dirs/xxxx/.  If you're using cassini you can change the virtual path to /dirs/xxx/

This should expose the routing issues you're having.  Typically for me it's related to javascript or some other function that's not going through the routing engine that I didn't notice generating the wrong url.

Comment: First off thank you for your reply.  I use cassini, tried adding the virtual path, re-built, and ran the project but could not access my pages until I took out the virtual path.  I really think the problem lies within the last sentence of your response, that is, "...it's related to javascript or some other function that's not going through the routing engine that I didn't notice generating the wrong url.", but I have not found it yet.